# SQL Server - "Column name or number of supplied value does not match table definition"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know there have been a number of questions that address this issue in the past and I understand why I'm getting this error.

I'm really after a shortcut, my table has hundreds of columns and I don't want to have to manually sift through the code checking the value against its field definition. The error message when I try to run it always points to the same line number - the line with the INSERT on it.

Is there an easy way to get it to point to the *actual* field it has a problem with?

EDIT: After reading the answers given, I realised that I did NOT understand the cause of this message at all. It was JUST a result of a missing field and not related to incorrect data type at all. When I added the missing fields, the error went away even though the data type was still wrong in some fields.

Fortunately, the answers and comments understood the ACTUAL cause of the problem rather than my assessment of it, so the problem was solved.

Comment: Intellisense in SQL Server Management Studio will highlight the invalid column name

Comment: Well that completely depends on what your `INSERT` statement is. It helps if you add it to your question *hint hint nudge nudge*

Comment: @JamiePollard I have 2 problems with that, 1) intellisense is highlighting EVERYTHING because it's a linked-server and 2) the field name is fine (for most of them) but I am (mostly) putting the wrong data type in the field.

Comment: The crux of your problem is right here, "my table has hundreds of columns". That is a huge red flag that the design is probably less than optimal.

Comment: @SeanLange There are very good reasons why my table has hundreds of columns. I am not an amateur.

Comment: I don't believe I stated that you are an amateur. Tables with hundreds of columns usually indicates that the design is not normalized. This is usually caused by repeating groups. As to the topic at hand there is simply no shortcut because it is impossible to know which column is "missing".

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an easy way to get it to point to the actual field it has a
>   problem with?

Of course not.   That would require an intuitive understanding of the programmer's actual INTENT, of which computers are not currently capable.

You've got an insert like:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (ColumnA, ColumnB, ... ColumnZ)
VALUES (ValueA, ValueC, ... ValueZ)
```

There's no way a computer could know that ColumnB should get ValueB and not ValueC, because maybe the programmer wanted it that way.  Therefore there's no way to programmatically know that ValueB is the value that's missing, or that ColumnB is the "problem column".

So no, there's no shortcut, sorry.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but it is clearly tripping up when I try to load "abc" into a numeric field called "AccountBalance", so why can't it just tell me that "AccountBalance" is the place where it failed...?

Comment: As Tab already said, how could the sql engine know that is the problem? When datatypes don't match an implicit conversion happens. If it threw up its hands everytime that happened it would be challenging when the author of the code wants that to happen.

Comment: Sometimes the parser does not directly point to where the error is but normally the error is close where it was pointed at. Say at line 17 is where the parser points out the error when in reality it was at line say 13. But in your case it would be probably be difficult because it is ONE big string, I guess.

Comment: @edper That's what I generally find, but in this case all errors point back to the line where the INSERT is situated.

Comment: @SeanLange Clearly an implicit conversion is NOT happening, because I'm getting an error. It know that an error has occurred, it is telling me so. It knows the error occurred on line X of the query, and it must have happened when it was trying to crowbar a value into an inappropriate field, why does it not know what field that was?

Comment: I think that you missed the point. How could it know that at column 10 (as an example) you didn't provide a value? The error message is that the number of columns and the number of values are not the same. How would the query engine know which column you didn't provide a value for?

Comment: @SeanLange In that sense, yes, you're right, but I know for a fact that I have the data type wrong for some of the fields and I was under the impression that this error message would be used to cover both error types...? With that in mind, I can either look down every line of the code and check the data type is right, or, I was hoping that the software would just tell me the ones where I've gone wrong. If it's jut telling me I have a missing column, that makes things much easier.

Comment: Yes all it is telling you is the number of columns and values are inconsistent. It couldn't possibly know what your intention was for what value maps to what column.

Comment: @Lefty No, the error message would be different and more informative if you had the correct number of columns/values.   When an implicit conversion fails, you get an error more like "conversion failed trying to convert 'ABC' to datatype int".   But the parser isn't even getting to that point because it sees that there's a mismatch in the number of columns/values.

Comment: @TabAlleman Thank you! I will check that I have a value for each column. To be honest, I thought it was OK to have some columns missing unless it was specified as "notnull" so I didn't expect to see this as a problem and leaped straight for the column-definition explanation.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is to structure the `insert` as:

```
insert into t(col1,
              col2,
              . . .
             )
    values (<whatever>,  -- col1
            <whatever>,  -- col2
            . . .
           );
```

This orders the expressions.  You can find a problem by pasting the two lists into a spreadsheet and manually comparing them.

Or, as I'm more likely to do:

```
insert into t(col1,
              col2,
              . . .
             )
    select <whatever> as col1,
           <whatever> as col2
            . . .
```

Of course, merely listing the columns being inserted may solve your problem.

Then, I would suggest that you revisit your table.  Having hundreds of columns in a table that is taking such inserts may be a bad idea.  There may be a better way to structure the table.

For the curious, MySQL has an interesting, non-standard solution.  It allows `set` in an `insert`, so you can explicitly set the column values.

Comment: The query is much too big to change the way it works, and there are very good reasons why there are so many columns. It was writing output to a table using SELECT INTO and this worked fine, I just want to change it to write to an almost identical table where some of the columns are defined differently. There is no scope for redesigning the table or rewriting the query.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an `SQL` solution. But I will probably make a small program just to map the field to values, and from there determine what's wrong.

Check my simple program in `JavaScript` that would [map-field-to-values](https://codepen.io/edper/pen/WZJKyy).

Comment: I like this! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome @Lefty. But did you try to put your `SQL` command string on my program and run it? If not try it and see if it works, or if you can also post the whole string of your `SQL` command on a **Google docs** for example and share the link afterwards.

Comment: no I haven't tried it yet because I managed to solved the problem "manually" by the time you posted this, but I will try it out at some point and will almost certainly use i in the future. I can't really put the SQL into the "public domain" because it's property of my company and the size of it would take too long to obfuscate it enough unfortunately.

Comment: @Lefty Glad to hear that you finally solved it! Congrats! That's what matters at this point! I perfectly understand not putting the SQL command in public. There is no problem about that for me.